# I would like to get by node.js app to serve up multiple html files

Tags: html, node.js, web-applications

So right now I have the following code to allow 'index.html' to be correctly displayed at:
http://staging-supermodels.herokuapp.com/

But my question is how can I change it so that my other files like SignIn.html also are displayed when a user click's the "Login" button? Thanks!

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express.createServer(express.logger());

var html_buffer = new Buffer(fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf-8'), 'utf-8');
var html_lines = html_buffer.toString("utf-8");

// public directory stores .css files
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/css_files'));

// handler for dynamic content(webpages that change over time)
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send(html_lines);
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code that you have posted you actually have the answer, app.get(). In order to serve an HTML file(or any file) the clients browser has to "get" the file, in this case an HTML file.

```
app.get('/Signin', function(request, response){
 response.send(''); // you will put path to your html file within the "('')"
});
```

Comment: So if my SignIn.html and index.html are in the same folder as my web.js file with the code I showned in my question how would this look. Thanks but I just want to be absolutely sure before I try it.

Comment: 'app.get('/', function(request, response){
  response.send('index') //If this doesn't work try 'index.html' instead
 };'

app.get('/signin', function(request, response){
 response.send('signing') // If this doesn't work try 'signing.html'
};

If these don't work let me know and I'll do some more research. I'm a little rusty with traditional node.js. I usually use express and jade. It's definitely worth looking into.